# A public action method was not found on controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a project on asp.net MVC3, I have a controller named UserProfile when i run my project and login, it shows error A public action method images was not found on controller UserProfile

I don't have any action method named images in any of my controllers,below is my UserProfile's index method

```
[CustomAuthorizeAttribute]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var userName = string.Empty;
        if (SessionHelper.GetSession("login") != null)
        { userName = SessionHelper.GetSession("login").ToString(); }
        else
        { return View(); }

        SessionHelper.SetSess("issetup", null);
        UserProfileModel model = GetUserProfileData(userName);
        StateandCityDropdown();
        return View(model);
    }
```

I have two forms on userprofile index view one with some textboxes and other fields for entering data and second for uploading images

Comment: Where did you see this error? Did you inspect the `Network` tab with FireBug? Seems like some `<img>` tag is pointing to an invalid controller action.

Comment: Yes i have inspected Network tab in firebug, it is not showing any thing there, this error is appearing on Elma error log(i am logging my errors with Elma)

Comment: You probably have some view in your application which is attempting to request an image from a wrong folder. The Network Tab of FireBug will tell you which as the request will probably end up with a 500 error.

Comment: Yes i am having one request with error 500 let me check it :)

Comment: I was having 500 error because of some image missing i fixed that,but still Elma is showing the same error A public action method images was not found on controller UserProfile

Comment: Well, seems like you haven't fixed it right then :-) Sorry I really cannot help you given the context and amount of information you provided.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like the routes are picking up on a url you have and mistaking them for an action. It could be that you have a link to an image directory underneath a directory that matches your controller such as /User/Images would thow this error because the routing would then expect you to have an Images action when you dont. Check the page source for anything linking to an images folder but without an image included. The other option is that the routes are picking up the images as well as the actions you want them to. If this is the case in your Global.asax.cs file check the RegisterRoutes method has some ignores in for images.

```
       routes.Ignore("{*allpng}", new { allpng = @".*\.png(/.*)?" });
       routes.Ignore("{*allgif}", new { allgif = @".*\.gif(/.*)?" });
       routes.Ignore("{*alljpg}", new { alljpg = @".*\.jpg(/.*)?" });
```

Hope this helps
Andy